# Angular : Redraw Pipe based on observable value

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have a bunch of custom pipe that are handling localization :

For example, here a simple pipe that will display fullname / lastname or lastname / fullname based on the language :

```
@Pipe({ name: 'fullname' })
export class FullnamePipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {
  private language = Language.EN_US;
  private subscriptions = new SubSink();

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.language = LanguageUtils.toAppLanguage(this.translateService.currentLang);
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(({ lang }) => {
        this.language = LanguageUtils.toAppLanguage(lang);
      })
    );
  }

  transform(value: string, language?: Language): string {
    const [firstname, lastname] = value.split('|');
    const firstNameFirst = LanguageUtils.isFirstNameFirst(language || this.language);
    return firstNameFirst ? `${firstname} ${lastname}` : `${lastname} ${firstname}`;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Now this is one of a bunch of pipes with the exact same functionality, just the transform method changes.

I would like for those pipes to be able to redraw themselves (so change their displayed value) based on `this.language` change.

Now, I know there is at least 2 solutions :

- Use `pure:false` and it would work since changing the language will trigger detection. But the downside of this is that the pipe runs EVERY time the detection trigger and not only language. So it's very overkill.
- add a parameter (like above) but this means every component that uses the pipe, needs to actually pass an observable to the pipe with the language value. This makes every component "smarter" than it should be.

Is there a solution where I can manually redraw a pipe based on when I want to ?

Comment: AFAIK the param values would need to change or the pipe would have to be set to `pure: false` for `transform` to be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting pipe to `{ pure: false }` is definitely not a performance problem unless you have thousands of those in a component.

The second proposition not only makes the component smarter, but would also involve `async` pipe which is also impure and has slightly higher performance hit than the first solution - not that, again, would be a problem unless you're doing something very wrong in your template.

If you need to redraw when the language changes in a `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` context, which I assume you have, since it has much higher performance impact than a simple impure pipe, do not forget to call `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck` inside the language subscription.

Comment: there are cases where I do have a hundred (they format a date based on the language local).

I guess I will go with it anyway. Thanks

Comment: I'd say a hundred is okayish. Your transform operation is so simple, that It would not make much difference if you cached the result of transform for last value.